# Use case for the principals(role arns) mentioned in aws elasticsearch domain IAM policy?

Tags: elasticsearch, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-elasticsearch

While going through IAM policy for AWS elasticsearch with terraform, i can see the options to add principals as role arns :

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "default" {
  count =  ( length(var.iam_role_arns) > 0) ? 1 : 0
  //for resources within 
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = distinct(compact(var.iam_actions))

    resources = [
      join("", aws_elasticsearch_domain.default.*.arn),
      "${join("", aws_elasticsearch_domain.default.*.arn)}/*"
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = distinct(compact(concat(var.iam_role_arns)))
    }
  }
}
```

while trying to access aws es from kibana dashboard i have to specify the condtional IPs to get access to the es domain. what should be the use case where these **var.iam_role_arns** are getting used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `iam_role_arns` to access your ES using **signed https queries** by your **IAM user/role** credentials. By default, ES nor AWS provide an option to create such queries, but they are **third party tools** for that, such as popular [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth#elasticsearch-py-client-usage-example) library for python.

The library also has an [example specific to ES](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth#elasticsearch-py-client-usage-example).

This can be very useful if you want to interact with your ES through a **lambda function or an EC2 instance**. In these cases, your `iam_role_arns` would refer to lambda execution and instance roles respectively. In this scenario, you could use `aws-requests-auth` to construct signed queries to your ES domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just check it out [Signing HTTP Requests to Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-python)